# How to read GPS device from /dev/gps?

Tags: linux, devices, sensors

I have a GPS module in my Linux board with Ubuntu 16.04 armhf on it (OrangePi 3G-IoT).

I need to read the GPS module's data. It exists in `/dev/gps`.

---

How can I read the `/dev/gps` device and get coordinates?

I have tried `cat /dev/gps` or `tail /dev/gps` but no values returned.

Is there any tool to read it?

---

Thanks!

Comment: You can try for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12911528/2908599

Comment: But it is reading from serial port, the gps device is on board?